# Unable to select a Link using XPath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Iam doing automation of a ecommerce site, iam facing a click link issue.

below is the link

```
http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Samsung
```

iam not able to click to the  Availability
    ***Exclude Out of Stock***

below is the html

```
<input type="checkbox" value="facets.availability%5B%5D=Exclude+Out+of+Stock" class="facetoption" autocomplete="off">
```

below xpath iam using

```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/ul/li/a/input")).click();


    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@value,'facets.availability%5B%5D=Exclude+Out+of+Stock']")).click();
```

getting an error.

```
FAILED: FlipkartTest
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@value,'facets.availability%5B%5D=Exclude+Out+of+Stock'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@value,'facets.availability%5B%5D=Exclude+Out+of+Stock'] because of the following error:
[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: "<unknown>"]
Command duration or timeout: 73 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'VALUED-8JGOG5PH', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: f6f56eba-4608-49e0-a0c7-4bd903ae142e
```

my second doubt is how to cut short the Xpath i don't want to use complete xpath like

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]/a")).click();


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[5]/a")).click();


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[6]/a")).click();
```

is there way to cutshort the xpath  to last selectors, only last li is changing.

Thanks

Comment: for the given link : http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Samsung. I dont see any **Availability Exclude Out of Stock**

Comment: Sorry under Availability, checkbox Exclude out of stock is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following xpath:

```
//li[@title='Exclude Out of Stock']/a"
```

Comment: Hi above xpath, is working fine, but one problem is there, on the page above should be visible, iam scrolling, manually scrolling down. how to scroll the page  iam using below commands  //      JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
//     jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", ""); but it is not working any suggestions